# Capstone not disassembling vpunpcklqdq, vprold, and vshufi32x4

Tags: ida, disassembly, disassemblers, x86-64, capstone

I am trying to disassemble a binary using Capstone. I noticed that there are some instructions that cannot be disassembled, e.g. the `vshufi32x4` instruction:

```
from capstone import *
from capstone.x86 import *

md = Cs(CS_ARCH_X86, CS_MODE_64)
md.detail = True

#instruction_bytes = b'b\x11\r(\xfe\xf6'
# The above instruction_bytes work as expected, the below print shows
# 0x6: vpaddd ymm14 , ymm14, ymm30               62110d28fef6

instruction_bytes = b'b\xf3}(C\xe4\x03'
# Capstone has problem with the above instruction_bytes.
# IDA Pro shows the instruction vshufi32x4 ymm4, ymm0, ymm4, 3

print(instruction_bytes.hex())  # '62f37d2843e403'
for c_i in md.disasm(instruction_bytes, len(instruction_bytes)):
    print(hex(c_i.address) + ":", c_i.mnemonic, c_i.op_str, "\t\t\t\t", c_i.bytes.hex())
```

Other examples which cannot be disassembled by Capstone are `vpunpcklqdq` and `vprold`

What is so special about these instructions? How can I make Capstone disassemble them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the issues in the Capstone repo, there seems to have been some problems/regressions with decoding AVX-512 instructions for the last couple of years:

https://github.com/capstone-engine/capstone/issues?q=is%3Aissue+avx

You could try building capstone from `next` and see if that works:

https://github.com/capstone-engine/capstone/tree/next

Comment: Using the `next` branch solved the problem.